# Verify Http Status Code for ~90K URLs with PHP

Tags: php, laravel, curl, guzzle

I have a list of 90K URLs and I need to verify the Http status code for each of them; and make an entry next to each URL in the database. Here's my attempt so far; but it's super slow. I'd appreciate any suggestions, feedback on making this run faster.

```
public function handle()
    {
        
        DB::table('internal_links')->whereNull('status')->orderBy('id')->chunk(5, function($links) {
           
           foreach($links as $link) {
                stream_context_get_default([
                    'http' => ['method' => 'HEAD']
                ]);
                $status_code = @get_headers($link->href)[0];
                if(!$status_code) {
                    $status_code = 404;
                } else {
                    $status_code = substr($status_code, 9,3);
                }
                DB::table('internal_links')->where('href', $link->href)->update(['status' => $status_code]);
           }
        });
        return Command::SUCCESS;
    }
```

In my test, this takes about ~6-7 hours to complete. I'd be happy if this can be done faster with concurrent requests. I'm currently exploring a way to build the concurrent requests with Laravel's Http client; but can't figure it out.

**Update**
I'm attempting to use Laravel Http concurrent requests; but not able to figure this out -

```
public function handle()
    {
        DB::table('internal_links')->distinct('href')->orderBy('id')->chunk(50, function($urls) {
            // How do I write the following block to have my "$urls as $url) go into the $pool->head($url) ?
            $responses = Http::pool(fn (Pool $pool) => [
                $pool->head('http://url1'),
                $pool->head('http://url2')
            ]);
        });
        return Command::SUCCESS;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you even need this? The fact a page returns a certain status at any given point in time is no guarantee that it will return the same status in future.

Comment: Anyway please show what you've tried in order to make concurrent requests, and explain what difficulty you're having specifically. Then we can help you fix it.

Comment: @ADyson - I've updated the original post with my latest attempt; but it's incomplete. Still trying to figure this out.

Also - this is to fix broken links of a site; and I'm ok the links returning 404 in future.

Comment: You're going to need to declare the pool after the callback. Inside the callback, just build the array of URLs. Then when that's done, you can pass the array to the pool command

Comment: Actually 4 request per second is not too bad depending on your targets... Also, are they all from different domains/servers? This could be seen as an attack if you keep sending those requests in such a short amount of time.